# Is it possible to return empty row from Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is this possible to return all columns in query as empty column (not null) or empty row, in case the actual query is returning no rows

Comment: So assuming your query returns 0 rows, what is it you want shown? Because returning all columns is redundant when it's the rows you require.

Comment: What is an empty column if it is not null?

Comment: oh thank , i got ur attention richard, i am looking for you as you definetly have answer...see my another question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297181/column-does-not-allow-nulls

Comment: so what i want is to return a empty row from there so as to avoid exception. Or is there any other approach.

Comment: I put an answer to this question, but looking at the other question, getting an answer to this will/may not solve that - which looks like a .net programming issue (of using the framework properly)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally, if you must have an empty row returned..

If your original query is

```
select a,b,c from tbl
```

You can turn it into a subquery

```
select t.a,t.b,t.c
from (select 1 as adummy) a
left join (
    select a,b,c from tbl  -- original query
) t on 1=1
```

Which ensures the query will always have a rowcount of at least one.

Comment: Very nice... not a recommended but a clever solution. Took me a good couple of minutes to figure it out *(but that's me offcourse)*.

Comment: Isn't the 2nd example, the same as a UNION?

Answer (score 6):

If your objective is to return a query with no records, or with an empty recordset/dataset, the following should work without any previous knowledge on the original query:

```
SELECT * FROM (myOriginalQuery) as mySelect WHERE 0 = 1
```

Comment: But if the original query does return rows, this will continuously return nothing, at least in SQL server. Don't know about other weirdo databases. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Richard's answer, you can use UNIONS to give you "something"...

```
select t.a, t.b, t.c
from (select null AS a, null AS b, null AS c
       union ALL
      select a, b, c from tbl)   -- original query
     ) AS t 
on 1=1
```

The '`1=1`' is really what forces SQL to return something.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Now you'll always have an extra row for non-empty result sets. I don't think you can get what the OP wanted with just union/union all.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to Karma, so here is a more full answer addressing some of the other users' comments:

#### Accepted Answer

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5297433/16569222) is of this form:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  ...your query...
), dummy AS (
  SELECT 1 AS dummy
) SELECT data.*
  FROM dummy
  LEFT JOIN data
```

This works because it joins your query's output rows against a single row then disregards the columns of that row. It is a `LEFT JOIN`, so when `a` contains rows and `b` does not, all rows of `a` will return with the `b` columns set to `NULL`.

This is great! Except this runs a JOIN the length of `b` which could be expensive.

#### Better answer

There is a [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57565922/16569222) that doesn't rely on column names and will not scan the table, which as noted in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297348/is-it-possible-to-return-empty-row-from-sql-server/57565922#comment101629391_57565922) will give an extra row.

This following query builds on that and uses a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to eliminate the extra row when it isn't needed.

```sql
WITH data AS (
  ...your query...
), nulls AS (
  SELECT
    null AS a,
    ...for each column output by your query...
) SELECT * FROM data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM nulls WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM data)
```

The major downside here is that you have to write out all of your columns as `NULL`, which will be hard in some situations.

#### Best answer

```sql
WITH data AS (
  ...your query...
), single_row AS (
  SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 1
), nulls AS (
  SELECT single_row.*
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS dummy) dummy
  LEFT JOIN single_row
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM single_row)
) SELECT * FROM data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM nulls
```

`nulls` will contain a row only when `data` does not. `nulls` gets its columns from a virtual row of `data`.