# Query Needs to Return Row When No Row Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a sql query (below) that doesn't work when today's date does not exist in the table.  How do I force it to return a blank row with no values except todays date in the date field? This is a year over year look back, but the key is looking at today's date.

```
select p.*
from [Apprise].[dbo].[adadjusttotal] c
--- Match
join (select distinct  a.adjustdate as curr_dte, max(b.adjustdate) over (partition by a.adjustdate) as prev_dte 
from [Apprise].[dbo].[adadjusttotal] a
join [Apprise].[dbo].[adadjusttotal] b  on year(a.adjustdate) -1 >= year(b.adjustdate) 
and month(a.adjustdate) >= month(b.adjustdate) 
and day(a.adjustdate) >=  day(b.adjustdate)
where a.adjustdate > getdate() -5 ) x
on c.adjustdate  = x.curr_dte
--- Prev Year
join [Apprise].[dbo].[adadjusttotal] p
on  p.adjustdate  = x.prev_dte               
where cast(c.adjustdate as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
and p.adjusttype = 'QuarterByDate'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to return empty row from Sql Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297348/is-it-possible-to-return-empty-row-from-sql-server)

Comment: I can't apply it in the same way.

Comment: Is this really correct in your sql: `day(a.adjustdate) >=  day(b.adjustdate)`? -- don't really see in what kind of logic the day of the month must be bigger than another day of the month, regardless of what month those are.

Comment: Just like the current date may not exist in the table, the previous years date may not exist as well.  So, I need it to pull the next previous business day's data for the prior year.

Answer (score 0):

Add this after the query:

```
if @@rowcount=0 
    select cast(getdate() as datetime),Null as col1,null as col2
```

or

```
if @@rowcount=0

    select convert(varchar(12), getdate(),101) as curdate, null as col1,null as col2
```

Comment: This adds an additional result set with that row, but it also returns the original empty results set

Comment: Though it's getting me a blank row for current year, neither of those answers are pulling the prior year's data as set up in the sql script.

Comment: I would execute the query and put the results into a temp table order by the date column. I would then do a select top 1 @curdate= date column order by date column desc. I would them compare if the @curdate= todays date and if not I would do a union with the blank row that I showed how to create plus the rows from the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
select p.*
from
(select 1 as dummy) x
outer apply (
    select p.*
    from [Apprise].[dbo].[adadjusttotal] c
    --- Match
    join (select distinct  a.adjustdate as curr_dte, max(b.adjustdate) over (partition by a.adjustdate) as prev_dte 
    from [Apprise].[dbo].[adadjusttotal] a
    join [Apprise].[dbo].[adadjusttotal] b  on year(a.adjustdate) -1 >= year(b.adjustdate) 
    and month(a.adjustdate) >= month(b.adjustdate) 
    and day(a.adjustdate) >=  day(b.adjustdate)
    where a.adjustdate > getdate() -5 ) x
    on c.adjustdate  = x.curr_dte
    --- Prev Year
    join [Apprise].[dbo].[adadjusttotal] p
    on  p.adjustdate  = x.prev_dte               
    where cast(c.adjustdate as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
    and p.adjusttype = 'QuarterByDate'
) p
```

Since this outer joins your data always with the 1 row, it should also return completely empty row when data doesn't actually exist.

Of course for any default values you need to add, you have to do that in the select clause. `select p.*` is there just to make it shorter, and I don't know what your columns are.

Comment: The user changed (or elucidated their requirements). The user wants results plus a blank row with today's date if a row with today's date does not exist.

Comment: Still doesn't return me last years data.