# How to get rid of the whitespace when rendering a subreport in the main report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have report that I'm running that uses 3 subreports. When the subreports are shown in the main report there's a white space in the backgroundwhenever they appear in the report.

I have a parameter passed to the subreport that will transfer the background color from the main to the sub. When the report is initially run the white space is filled with the corresponding background color of the row in the preview. But when I export to PDF or scroll to the next page it turns back to the white space.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5297433/10177680

This is the method I used for each subreport. I was able to produce a null row where there was no corresponding information with a 0 in SSMS. Then in SSRS I replaced the 0 with "". This successfully solved my issue.

I also had to clear the report data cache.