# SQL Query with Exists in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a query I have built that is to pull records up if changes are found in a change log table based on certain fields in my database being changed.  If changes aren't made, no record exists.  I have built my query which works really well to give me what I want BUT the problem is that when I narrow this down to a date range, if there are no records in the changelog to check against, I get nothing back.  Is there a way to do a "If Exists" of sorts in the where statement to check for date and if a record doesn't exist, still allow results to come back since I have coded result text in my select statement?  Here is my code:

```
Declare @StartDate as date
Declare @EndDate as date

Set @StartDate = '9/20/2021'
Set @EndDate = '10/1/2021'


Select DISTINCT n.ID, n.FULL_NAME, n.Company, n.Status, n.Email, 
    Case 
        when Coalesce(CLDP.CurrentValue, 'No Update Found') <> 'No Update Found' then CLDP.CurrentValue
        When Coalesce(CLDP.CurrentValue, 'No Update Found') = 'No Update Found' and b.PROFESSION <> '' then b.PROFESSION
        when Coalesce(CLDP.CurrentValue, 'No Update Found') = 'No Update Found' and b.PROFESSION = '' then 'No Update Found'
    end as ProfessionUpdate,

    Case 
        when Coalesce(CLDE.CurrentValue, 'No Update Found') <> 'No Update Found' then CLDE.CurrentValue
        When Coalesce(CLDE.CurrentValue, 'No Update Found') = 'No Update Found' and b.ETHNICITY <> '' then b.ETHNICITY
        when Coalesce(CLDE.CurrentValue, 'No Update Found') = 'No Update Found' and b.ETHNICITY = '' then 'No Update Found'
    end as EthnicityUpdate,

    Case 
        when Coalesce(CLDG.CurrentValue, 'No Update Found') <> 'No Update Found' then CLDG.CurrentValue
        When Coalesce(CLDG.CurrentValue, 'No Update Found') = 'No Update Found' and b.Gender <> '' then b.Gender
        when Coalesce(CLDG.CurrentValue, 'No Update Found') = 'No Update Found' and b.Gender = '' then 'No Update Found'
    end as GenderUpdate,

    Case 
        when Coalesce(nl.LOG_TEXT, 'No Update Found') <> 'No Update Found' then nl.Log_Text 
        When Coalesce(nl.LOG_TEXT, 'No Update Found') = 'No Update Found' and Cast(n.BIRTH_DATE as varchar) <> '' then Cast(n.BIRTH_DATE as VarChar)
        when Coalesce(nl.LOG_TEXT, 'No Update Found') = 'No Update Found' and Cast(n.BIRTH_DATE as varchar) = '' then 'No Update Found'
    end as BirthDateUpdate

from Customer as n inner join
    Members as b on b.ID = n.ID left join
    Profession as CLDP on n.ID = CLDP.ID left join
    Ethnicity as CLDE on n.ID = CLDE.ID Left Join
    Gender as CLDG on n.ID = CLDG.ID Left Join
    BirthDate as nl on nl.ID = n.ID 
Where n.ID in ('12345', '67890') and  
    cldp.createdon between @startDate and @endDate and 
    clde.createdon between @startdate and @enddate and 
    cldg.createdon between @startdate and @enddate and 
    nl.date_time between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Comment: You can check the date for null

Comment: So run a coalesce in the were statement or an IS NULL?  In the case of a test I ran today, the query resulted in no data because 3 of the 4 tables pulling from have nothing in them at all for the ID's in question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to return empty row from Sql Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297348/is-it-possible-to-return-empty-row-from-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `outer apply` with left table containing a single dummy row. Like the below:

> ```
> select *
>   into t
> from(values
>     (1, 'a'),
>     (2, 'b'),
>     (3, 'c')
> ) as t(id, val)
> ```

> ```
> select t.*
> from (
>   select 1 as dummy
> ) as dummy
>   outer apply (
>     select *
>     /*Your query goes here*/
>     from t
>     where id > 10
>   ) as t
> ```
>
> ```
>   id | val 
> ---: | :---
> null | null
> ```

> ```
> select t.*
> from (
>   select 1 as dummy
> ) as dummy
>   outer apply (
>     select *
>     /*Your query goes here*/
>     from t
>     where id > 1
>   ) as t
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | :--
>  2 | b  
>  3 | c
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22bdd651b541cd6ed343a818a0b0da86)*